# Где репозиторий?

Tags: веб-программирование, bitbucket, репозиторий

Зарегистрировался на Bitbucket. Там есть репозиторий, к которому я имею доступ. Название репозитория мне сказали, но я не могу найти его.
Подскажите, где там его искать?

Answer (score 4):

Ссылка на репозиторий в общем виде:

```
https://bitbucket.org/{user-or-company-name}/{repository-name}
```

Answer (score 0):

После авторизации на главной! (только что проверил, там они все есть)